# migrate bootstrap 2.3 to 3.0 with .less file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dotless

We are currently running bootstrap 2.3 in our application of over 400 html files. We decided the best way to upgrade to twitter bootstrap 3.0 without having to change all of our html files would be to include a .less file that references all the changes from 2.3 to 3.0. For Example: span6 in 3.0 is now col-md-6. Does anyone have a file that embeds all the old properties into a .less file that we could reference?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, changing over isn't that bad. I have done this on a couple sites using find/sed (I'm on a Mac) by simply updating the old classes to the new. It will get the bulk of the upgrade done quickly.

Use this page for reference on which classes you need to update: http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/